# HH:MM am/pm not fetch from nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to fetch the hours:minutes AM/PM from the nsdate.

```
NSDate *globalDateTime; //globaldate is : 2016-10-20 06:49:00 +0000 (UTC) 
NSString *dateString12 = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:globalDateTime
                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];    
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString12);
```

Result I am getting is NSString format: 20/10/16, 2:03:00 PM India Standard Time

Expected result is NSString format: 20/10/16,  6:49:00 PM India Standard Time

Or is there any way I only get expected result in NSString format : 6:49 PM

`dateString12` is get in NSLog is something in UTC format or some other format. It is giving me proper date but not giving me proper time.

Please help me how should I get proper time.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. `dateString12` is in local time. That's what you want, correct?

Comment: @rmaddy yes. But i am not getting the local time. I think it is converting into UTC or some other format.

Comment: You are getting the local time. That's what `NSDateFormatter` does by default. When you view the value of `globalDateTime` you see its value in UTC time, not India time. The value of `dateString12` will be in the local time for whatever device you run the code on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];// change here as per your need
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate: globalDateTime];
```

Comment: i also tried this code . it working fine . i upload screeshot here .

Comment: The real problem with this answer is it has nothing to do with the question being asked. The OP is just misunderstanding how dates work. The code in the question is fine.

Comment: problem is [NSDATE date] is showing time of 05:10:10  and stringfromDate is showing 10:37AM . I want stringfromdate = 05:10AM

Comment: @iosdeveloper No you don't. You don't seem to understand that the log output of `NSDate` shows the date in UTC. If you want local time, simply use `NSDateFormat` and you are fine.

Comment: @iosdeveloper Welcome.

Comment: This answer conflicts with your question. Your question states that viewing the date shows UTC time and you say that time is incorrect. So your question states you do not want UTC time. Then why did you accept an answer that formats the date into UTC time?